# How this ruby script using twitter api scrapes user ids?

Tags: ruby, api, twitter

Hello I have modified this older code to scrape twitter usernames, but for some reason it also scrapes user ids. I dont understand how it does that, since I dont see anywhere in the code "user_id" which you should use to get user ids according to twitter api documentation.
Here is the code

```
def my_usernames
  "UHDTelevisions"
end

def my_userinfo(names)
  @client.followers(names)
end

def my_userhash(users)
  userhash = {}
  users.each do |user|
    userhash[user.screen_name] = user.id.to_s
  end
  return userhash
end

def my_users
  my_userhash(my_userinfo(my_usernames))
end

def my_csv(my_users)
  CSV.open('./my_users.csv','a+') do |csv|
    my_users.each do |k,v|
    csv << [k,v]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the line that builds a hash `{name ⇒ id}`:

```
userhash[user.screen_name] = user.id.to_s
```

Here we already got the `user` object, that contains `id` amongst other user params. To return the list of names, one might simply:

```
@client.followers("UHDTelevisions").map &:screen_name
```

instead of all the code above.

Comment: I dont really understand this, how will such short code save the results to csv file?

Comment: To save the result into the file, the line would be a bit longer: `File.write('./my_users.csv', @client.followers("UHDTelevisions").map(&:screen_name).join(','))`.

Comment: I just found out I cannot use client.followers, but I have to use client.follower_ids, however when I tried that in your code I got error that it does not recognize screen_name

Comment: When I deleted everything unnecesary, so the code looks like this: `print @client.follower_ids("detnewsRodBeard")` Im getting instead if IDs just this: Twitter::Cursor:0x3203220

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to keep a parallel structure you could change it to have my_userarray (since you only need values, not key-value pairs, I assume)

```
def my_userarray(users)
  userarray = []
  users.each do |user|
    userarray << user.screen_name
  end
  return userarray
end
```

You would need to update the my_users method as well, of course, to reflect the new method name for my_userarray

Comment: thanks a lot, I found error in my code, i need to use client.follower_ids instead of client.followers, but when i tried with this code, getting error that it does not recognize screen_name and when i delete it, i get various other errors.